# ssh to a server, run couple of manual commands and exit

Tags: shell-script, ssh

Is it possible to create a script that can ssh to multiple hosts one after another (not parallel) and wait till I exit the existing ssh session?

I've 50+ hosts. Here are the steps:

1. SSH host 1
2. From host 1 command prompt, run a set of operations (manually) and exit  the session (manually).
3. The script automatically detects the exit and SSH to the next host.

Trying to make use of the existing tools in rhel 6.x. I was just wondering if someone has done it with built-in tools

I could do something like this: but I just need to know how to make the script to wait till I finish the operations.

```
usr=test
svrs=("192.168.18.48" "192.168.191.237" )
for x in ${!svrs[*]} ; do
        ip=`echo ${svrs[x]}`
        ssh $usr@$ip
done
```

Comment: Maybe you want [pssh](https://github.com/lilydjwg/pssh)

Comment: Sure, but I'm trying to make use of the existing tools in rhel 6.x. So that I can skip the approval process. But if it is not possible, that's OK. I was just wondering if someone has done it with built-in tools.

Comment: Just a note: Avoid structures like this one: > ip=`echo ${svrs[x]}` and use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: That should go into your question. In general, don't comment your own question, but **edit your question** to improve it

Comment: Standard "oldschool" way to simulate manually written commands is to write an `expect` script. Although this can get tedious rather quickly. If you try to automate administration tasks, it is probably better to distribute script that does what you want onto the machines - you can always use some management tool to keep it versioned and synced across all hosts.

Comment: I would use Ansible with `serial: 1`. https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/246/how-do-i-run-ansible-on-one-host-at-a-time-and-break-on-a-failure

Comment: `for ip in ${svrs[*]}; do` will avoid the `echo` (but not solve your `ssh` problem) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly like that.

From the viewpoint of the shell, `ssh $usr@$ip` is no different from starting any other program, which might interact with the user. Since the program's input and output has not been redirected and the program is not being run in the background, the program will be free to interact with the user as it pleases.

You don't have to do anything special to "make the script wait until you finish the operations": the script will wait until the "ssh" command completes, or in other words, until the SSH session is ended.